# Python regular expression with codons

Tags: python, regex

Struggling with RE to search for sequences 'TAA' (triplets of 3 characters) 'TAA' again.

I tried the following:

`re.findall('TAA...+?TAA',seq)` which of course does not give triplets but does give me sequences

`re.findall('TAA([ATGC]{3})+?TAA' , seq)` however gives me a list as output

```
'AGG', 'TCT', 'GTG', 'TGG', 'TGA', 'TAT',
```

Any ideas? As I of course can check the output from

`re.findall('TAA...+?TAA',seq)`

if length % 3 == 0, but how to do this with RE?

Comment: Is TAA TAA TAA a valid capture (TAA being out of chance also the middle triplet of 3 characters)?

Answer (score 4):

You want a non-capturing group.

> `(?:...)`
>
> A non-capturing version of regular parentheses. Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses, but the substring matched by the group cannot be retrieved after performing a match or referenced later in the pattern.

Try this:

```
re.findall('TAA(?:[ATGC]{3})+?TAA' , seq)
```

Comment: Happen to have an idea to combine this with TAA TAG TGA as an first or last encounter??

Comment: Solution to myself for others to use: re.findall('(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)(?:[ATGC]{3})+?(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)' , seq)